# Is it good practise to use angular.element("[ng-controller="someCtrl"]").scope()

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Is it good practise to use `angular.element("ng-controller="someCtrl"]").scope()`  instead of using factory to handle data flow between controllers using dependency injection. The problem here is I want to call a function of another controller, so there are two ways either I put it in a factory and reuse it among controllers or use above syntax to call the function directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to call a function from other controller, it should be a SERVICE/Factory.  This way, you will share code between controllers, and you will code with good practices.

As they say in [angularjs docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services)

> Angular services are substitutable objects that are wired together
>   using dependency injection (DI). You can use services to organize and
>   share code across your app.

Then, you just need to create a service or a factory

```
//The service
angular.module('myApp')
  .service('serviceName', function ($http, $scope, socket) {
 //This functions will be available in your controller
    return {
      list: function () {
        $http.get(listUrl).success(function (lista) {
          $scope.centerList = lista;
          socket.syncUpdates('center', $scope.centerList);
        });
      }
    };
  });

//The controller
angular.module('myApp').controller('myCtrl', function ($scope, centerService) {

$scope.listCenters = function () {
  centerService.list();
};
});
```

Just to clarify, and to add some comprehensive ideas about services and factories:

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J6qr6Wx3VPs
- [AngularJS: Service vs provider vs factory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15666048/service-vs-provider-vs-factory)
- https://www.airpair.com/angularjs/posts/top-10-mistakes-angularjs-developers-make

Answer (score 2):

It is never good practice to access the DOM from a controller. So if wrapping the method in a factory/service is an option, I'd say that's the way to go.